# Calculate the sine of a float (in radians)…

Tags: code-golf

…without using any operator/function besides addition (`+`), subtraction (`-`), multiplication (`*`), division (`/`), modulo (`%`), exponent/power `pow()` or any of the standard C bitwise operators (`<<, >>, ~, &, |, ^`) or unary operators (`—, ++`) or assignment/comparison operators (`=, ==`).

If these symbols represent a different operation in your chosen language, go with the spirit of the question and don't use them.

Rules:

- You cannot use any mathematical functions your language might offer (Mathematica, looking at you.)
- You cannot use any operator besides the bitwise operators or the arithmetic operators listed above.
- Your output should be a float and be correct to at least 2 decimal places when truncated/rounded.
- You can use constants your language's **standard libraries** might provide.
- You can hardcode the values, but your program should work correctly for all floats (up to 2 decimal places) between `0` and `2π`;

This is code-golf, so the shortest answer wins.

Example:

```
Input: 3.141592653 / 2
Output: 1.00xxxxxx…
```

Please also post an ungolfed version of your code.

Comment: The tag [tag:code-challenge] needs an objective winning criterion.

Comment: @Howard Updated the tags.

Comment: I don't think that this is a good [tag:popularity-contest]. Most answer will go for the trivial solution and it will be a who-posts-first-will-get-most-upvotes challenge.

Comment: @Howard Changed it to a code-golf.

Comment: I assume that `^` is XOR and `!` is bitwise NOT?

Comment: @ProgramFOX `!` is logical NOT and `~` is bitwise NOT.

Comment: Err, where is the `=` and comparison operator? Are we disallowed to use them?

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳ Sorry! Updated.

Comment: *The sandbox is too dormant* The sandbox isn't dormant in any way. As you just notice yourself (after more than 10 edits in the last 30 minutes) it requires time and thought to produce a good challenge. The sandbox is just the right place to iron out any dents in your question. That's the purpose of the sandbox - to keep this noise from entering the main page.

Comment: @Howard Sorry, I will use the sandbox from now on.

Comment: Most of the current answers seem to violate the letter of the question without violating the spirit. In particular, with the exception of the APL one they all use one of `<`, `>`, or `^` meaning to-the-power-of rather than bitwise-XOR. Whether you prefer to comment on those answers and inform their submitters that they're invalid, or to edit the question to permit them, you could make things a lot clearer by listing the operators by *name*, not symbol in some unspecified language, and by grouping them with some kind of title or label (comparison, bitwise, arithmetic, assignment).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I have edited the question to clarify. I chose to permit exponentiation.

Comment: @duci9y do we need to give input like (pie)/2 or the calculated value((pie)/2 = 1.57xxxxx) ? and till what decimal places ?

Comment: please disallow imaginary exponentiation as this uses the sine function to be calculated and makes this to easy.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, even the sine function provided by libraries will not meet the trucation criterion: You can most likely find an x such that sin(x) = a.bc9999… (with a, b, c being some digits) and thus the output being a.bd0000… (with d = c+1). Therefore matching this criterion as it stands would be very nasty. Also, I would not know any language where `exp` is the exponent operator (or exponentiation) and not the exponential function.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Please read the first line of the question which refers to an "operator/ **function** ". And if you round the answer, you can meet the truncation rule.

Comment: @duci9y: 1) So, I may use the exponential function (e^x), but not general exponentiation (a^x for a ≠ e)? 2) Some example: sin(3.136) ≈ 0.00559262443555. Rounding to two digits and trucating would get me 0.01. Just truncating gets me 0.00. Would 0.01 be an acceptable answer? If so, why is 0.998 not an acceptable answer for sin(π/2)? Also: Why not just require the answer to deviate less than 0.01 from the actual answer?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft You can use general exponentiation.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, the trunction criterion isn't too hard to meet: write a sensible implementation and add 0.5 ulp.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Depends on how you interpret the criterion: If you require that your solution and the correct solution must be identical when truncated to two decimal places, you can always find an input such that this criterion is not met (as explained above). Anyway, now the criterion has been changed to “rounded/truncated” – no idea what that is supposed to exactly mean, not that I care anymore. You might also want to take a look at the comments regarding this criterion on [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23336/11354).

Answer (score 7):

### Python <strike>83</strike> 69

*Based on [Bhaskara I's sine approximation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhaskara_I%27s_sine_approximation_formula)*

**Implementation**

```
def f(x):p=3.14;x,s=x%p,(4,-4,4)[int(x/p)];return s/(12.34/x/(p-x)-1)
```

**Ungolfed**

```
def apxsine(radian):
    pi = 3.14 # Approximate to 2 decimal places
    sign = (4,-4,4)[radian % pi]
    return sign / (12.34/radian/(pi - radian) - 1))
```

**Deduction**

[image]

**Demo**

```
>>> from math import pi, sin
>>> any(round(abs(f(e) - sin(e)), 2) for e in (e/180.*pi for e in range(0,360)))
False
```

JUst realized that if I would have opted for [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) route, the code would be shorter (49 characters). But then it uses Complex numbers and am not sure if the call to the real method would be valid in the current question context.

```
f=lambda x:((2.72**(x*1j)-2.72**(-x*1j))/2j).real
```

Comment: Running `f(3.141592653 / 2)` returns `0.998…`. Your answer should be valid to at least two decimal places (`1.00…`). Please tell me if I did something wrong.

Comment: @duci9y: I believe, you need to round the result to two decimal place. `round(f(3.141592653 / 2),2)`, instead of truncating

Comment: @duci9y Abhijit is right, you're truncating.  The answer does give correct results.

Comment: Then I think you should include the `round()` in your code.

Comment: @duci9y: Your question demanded a result which is precise to 2 decimal places `Your output should be a float and be correct to at least 2 decimal places.`, so mathematically speaking that's rounding rather than truncating.

Comment: @Abhijit I included an example in the question. You really should put the `round()` into your code. Also, the `real` method would be invalid.

Comment: @duci9y His answer is accurate to two decimal places. 1.00 is the same as .998 to two decimal places.

Comment: You need to change `[4,-4]` to `[4,-4,4]` in the second line, otherwise this won’t work for x = 6.282 < 2π.

Comment: PS: or you could use a library’s π – which would also shorten your code, if you do not count the `import` line.

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript <strike>114</strike> 77

Using Taylor Series expansion at 0:

```
function s(y){
    var p=2*Math.PI,
        // z = sign (y)
        z=(y>0?1:-1),
        // x = (abs(y) mod 2 PI - PI) * sign(y) => put x in [-PI, PI] range
        x=-z*((z*y)%p-p/2),
        // u = x^2
        u=x*x; 
        // return Taylor Expansion
        return x*(1-(1-(1-(1-u/72)*u/42)*u/20)*u/6);
}
```

Golfed (114):

```
function s(y){var z=(y>0?1:-1),p=2*Math.PI,x=-z*((z*y)%p-p/2),u=x*x; return x*(1-(1-(1-(1-u/72)*u/42)*u/20)*u/6);}
```

**Edit**

"Improved" for y in [0,2PI], golfed (77) :

```
function s(y){var x=3.14-y,u=x*x;return x*(1-(1-(1-(1-u/72)*u/42)*u/20)*u/6)}
```

Another version for more precision (varying k) :

```
function s(y){
    var p=2*Math.PI,
        // z = sign (y)
        z=(y>0?1:-1),
        // x = (abs(y) mod 2 PI - PI) * sign(y) => put x in [-PI, PI] range
        x=-z*((z*y)%p-p/2),
        // u = x^2
        u=x*x,
        // k = 2* expansion level +1
        k=9,
        // r = 1 initial value
        r = 1; 

        // Taylor Expansion
        // while k > 1
        for(;k>1;) { 
            r= 1 - r*u /k--/k--; 
        }
        return x*r;
 }
```

Golfed (114):

```
function s(y){var z=(y>0?1:-1),p=2*Math.PI,x=-z*((z*y)%p-p/2),u=x*x,k=9,r=1;for(;k>1;)r=1-r*u/k--/k--;return x*r;}
```

Comment: Please post an ungolfed version too.

Comment: @duci9y ungolfed version given

Answer (score 5):

### MATLAB 35

Too bad `e` is not a constant in Matlab. That would have saved me 10 characters. I will see if I can come up with a solution for this.

```
@(x)(2.7183^(x*i)-2.7183^(-x*i))/2i
```

Comment: May be you can try the approximate value as `2.72`? After all the question dictates that the precision  could be within 2 decimal places.

Comment: I tried this, but for all values between 0 and 2pi, this was the minimum required definition of e in order to get the desired accuracy.

Comment: Strange, I tried your implementation in Python, and it seems to give me correct result. Unfortunately, I do not have Matlab to try this out :-)

Comment: And when you try it with an input of 6.28?

Comment: If I round the result to 2 decimal places it matches i.e. the formula with 2 decimal approximation of `e` gives `-0.0031853017931379904` where as sin returns `0.0007829010740853711`, which are both zero approximate to 2 decimal places. Refer http://ideone.com/I6Ifld

Comment: You are right, sorry, I gave the wrong example. Try it for 1.47. 1.47 that sneaky bastard ;)

Answer (score 4):

## APL - 21

```
{|{.5×⍵-+⍵}0J1*⍵÷○.5}
```

This uses the fact that `sin pi*x/2 = Im[(-1)^x]`.

[Example test on ngn APL](http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/#code=%7B%7C%7B.5%D7%u2375-+%u2375%7D0J1*%u2375%F7%u25CB2%7D%203.1415926535%D72)

Previous answer: 26

```
{-/((×\9⍴⍵)÷×\1+⍳9)[2×⍳5]}
```

This uses the Taylor/Maclaurin series up to 9th term.

[Example test on ngn APL](http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/#code=%7B-/%28%28%D7%5C9%u2374%u2375%29%F7%D7%5C1+%u23739%29%5B2%D7%u23735%5D%7D%203.1415926535%F72)

Note about operators: only operators used were `/\⍴⍳` which don't have anything to do with arithmetic, and are mostly list manipulation tools, `○` which is *multiply by pi*, and `+-×÷*` which are permitted by the rules

Comment: The 20 character line seems to give wrong answers?

Comment: @mmumboss Yeah, sorry, fixed

Comment: Your example link gives wrong result and does not match your post. Save nine bytes: [`11○0J1*2÷○∘÷`](http://tryapl.org/?a=%2811%u25CB0J1*2%F7%u25CB%u2218%F7%29%203.1415926535%F72&run)

Comment: `11○` is just shorthand for `|{.5×⍵-+⍵}`.

Answer (score 4):

## C++ <strike>80</strike>  68(excluding white-spaces + edit)

#### GOLFED

```
float S(float x){float z=x*x,y=x*(5040-(840+(42-z)*z)*z)/5040;return y;}
```

#### UNGOLFED

both versions are different so that, it is easy to get output.

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    float x,y,z;
    for(;;)
    {
        std::cin>>x;
        z=x*x;
        y=(x*(5040-840*z+42*z-z*z*z))/5040;
        std::cout<<y<<'\n';
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
1.047197 ((pie)/3)
0.865096 (sin((pie)/3) = 1.73201/2 = 0.8660)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell

```
import Prelude hiding (sin)
import Data.Complex
sin x=(\(_:+y) -> y) $ exp (0 :+ x)
```

Uses Euler's formula. `(y :+ z)=y+zi` I think.

Comment: Is imagPart a mathematical function?

Comment: I would consider complex arithmetics with exp cheating, as in complex, exp and trig are the same. Otherwise, there's an unfair advantage.

Comment: Sorry, not a valid answer.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, got rid of outside math function. (It wasn't much of a math function, but it is gone now.)

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript (56)

```javascript
j=x=+prompt(r=0);for(i=1;i<99;j*=x/++i)r+=i&1?i&2?-j:j:0
```

[Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) used here.
`x` is the input value,  `r` is the result, `j` contains `x^i/i!`
The result is output in console.

```javascript
x=prompt();
r=0;
j=1;
for(i=1;i<99;i++) {
  j=j*x/i;
  if (i%2) {
    if (i%4 == 1) r+=j;
    else r-=j;
  }
}
alert(r);
```

If evaluation is needed for input (for example `3.141592653 / 2`) :

```javascript
j=x=eval(prompt(r=0));for(i=1;i<99;j*=x/++i)r+=i&1?i&2?-j:j:0
```

Comment: Bravo... a lot more compact than my: `f=n=>+!n||n*f(n-1);for(x=prompt(),y=s=0;9>=y;y++)s+=Math.pow(-1,y)*Math.pow(x,z=2*y+1)/f(z);alert(s)`

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 70 bytes

Using sin(x) = Im(exp(ix)) and the series for the exponential function:

```python
def s(x):
    s,f=0,1
    for i in range(1,50):f*=1j*x/i;s+=f
    return s.imag
```

Note that `imag` is not a function here, strictly speaking.

Ungolfed:

```python
def s(x):
    s = 0
    f = 1
    for i in range(1,50):
        f *= 1j*x/i
        s += f
    return s.imag
```

Answer (score 1):

#### R, 80 chars

```
f=function(x){a=seq(1,99,2);sum((-1)^(0:49)*(x^a)/sapply(mapply(`:`,1,a),prod))}
```

Uses [Taylor approximation](http://www.math.utah.edu/~kitchen/1220F06/sine.html) at an order of 99. 
`sapply` and `mapply` are just functions to vectorize the operation, while `sum` and `prod` are just vectorized `+` and `*`.

```
> b=seq(0,2*pi,1e5)
> all((f(b)-sin(b))<.01)
[1] TRUE
```

If the `*apply` functions are a problem, here is a solution at 91 characters:

```
f=function(x){a=0:100;b=c();for(i in 1:50)b[i]=(-1)^(i-1)*(x^a[2*i])/prod(1:a[2*i]);sum(b)}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C 70

This one is not only golf but also useful in microcontrollers without floating point instructions or math libraries:

```
float S(float a){float x,y=1,h=1e-4;while(x+=h*(y-=h*x),(a-=h)>0);return x;}
```

Of course, the majority of the characters is taken by these annoyingly long type declarations and return. If the function declaration doesn't count, it's much shorter. If we take the value by pointer and overwrite it (removing the return statement), we get 71 characters.

```
S(float*x){float a=*x,y=1,h=1e-4;*x=0;while(*x+=h*(y-=h**x),(a-=h)>0);}
```

However, it complains about default return value.

EDIT: 70, for is shorter:

```
S(float*x){float a=*x,y=1,h=1e-4;*x=0;for(;(a-=h)>0;*x+=h*(y-=h**x));}
```

EDIT2: forgot ungolfed version

```
float fake_sin(float a){
   float x=0,y=1;
   float h=1e-4;//adjust for accuracy
   while(a>0){
      y-=h*x;
      x+=h*y;
      a-=h;
   }
   return x;//return y for cosine or y/x for tangent
}
```

It takes arbitrary positive angle, but doesn't work for negative.

Answer (score 1):

### Java - 108 / 81

```java
float s(float p){for(float q=p-=3.14,d=p=-p,i=1,m=1;i<11;)p+=(q*=d*d)/(m*=++i*++i)*(((int)i&2)-1);return p;}
```

Without the function declaration, it's just doing `p = sin(p)`:

```java
for(float q=p-=3.14,d=p=-p,i=1,m=1;i<11;)p+=(q*=d*d)/(m*=++i*++i)*(((int)i&2)-1);
```

The error is max ±0.00201 in the range 0..2π, much worse in either direction.

Ungolfed:

```java
float s(float p) {
    for (float q = p -= 3.14, d = p = -p, i = 1, m = 1; i < 11;)
        p += (q *= d * d) / (m *= ++i * ++i) * (((int)i & 2) - 1);
    return p;
}
```

Unobfuscated:

```java
float sin(double ph) {
    float [] dividers = {-1, 6, -120, 5040, -362880, 39916800L};
    ph -= Math.PI;
    double d = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        d += Math.pow(ph, i * 2 + 1) / dividers[i];
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C# - <strike>115</strike> 103

This code uses an approximation of [Maclaurin series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) calculation of the sine of x, and is accurate to 7 decimal places.

`float x=0;for(int i=1;i<96;i+=2){float n=i,d=1,p=a;while(n>1){d*=n;n--;p*=a;}x+=((i+1)%4==0?-1:1)*p/d;}`

Where `a` is the input in radians.

Here's the code with whitespaces:

```
float x = 0; for (int i = 1; i < 96; i += 2)
{
    float n = i, d = 1, p = a;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        d *= n;
        n--;
        p *= a;
    }
    x += ((i+1)%4==0?-1:1)*p / d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-84 BASIC, 21 bytes

```
(e^(iAns)-e^(⁻iAns))/2i
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 6, <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```perl6
{(e**(i*$_)).im}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 139 bytes

```
s(x:Float):Complex Float==(digits()>20=>%i;x>2*%pi=>s(x-2*%pi);x< -2*%pi=>s(x+2*%pi);imag(reduce(+,[(%i*x)^k/factorial(k)for k in 0..40])))
```

I see this formula in the other solutions and I inplemented it in Axiom...
The formula i follow is this:

```
                               +oo
                               ----
                               \      (i*x)^k
sin(x)=ImPart(e^(i*x))=imPart( /     --------  )
                               ----k     k!
                                 0
```

ungolf

```
sin1(x:Float):Complex Float==
              digits()>20=>%i
              x>  2*%pi  =>sin1(x-2*%pi)
              x< -2*%pi  =>sin1(x+2*%pi)
              imag(reduce(+,[(%i*x)^k/factorial(k)for k in 0..40]))
```

there is some problem for the last 2 digits each number; some test cases:

```
(79) -> [-23, numeric(sin(-23)), s(-23) ]
   (79)  [- 23.0,0.8462204041 7517063524,0.8462204041 7517063514]
                                                 Type: List Complex Float
(80) -> [ 23, numeric(sin( 23)), s( 23) ]
   (80)  [23.0,- 0.8462204041 7517063524,- 0.8462204041 7517063536]
                                                 Type: List Complex Float
(81) -> [[x/2,numeric(sin(x/2)),s(x/2)] for x in 0..(7*2)]
   (81)
                  1
   [[0,0.0,0.0], [-,0.4794255386 0420300027,0.4794255386 0420300027],
                  2
    [1,0.8414709848 0789650665,0.8414709848 0789650665],
     3
    [-,0.9974949866 0405443094,0.9974949866 0405443093],
     2
    [2,0.9092974268 256816954,0.9092974268 256816954],
     5
    [-,0.5984721441 0395649405,0.5984721441 0395649405],
     2
    [3,0.1411200080 598672221,0.1411200080 5986722208],
     7
    [-,- 0.3507832276 8961984812,- 0.3507832276 8961984817],
     2
    [4,- 0.7568024953 0792825138,- 0.7568024953 0792825139],
     9
    [-,- 0.9775301176 6509705539,- 0.9775301176 6509705545],
     2
    [5,- 0.9589242746 6313846889,- 0.9589242746 6313846888],
     11
    [--,- 0.7055403255 7039190623,- 0.7055403255 7039190626],
      2
    [6,- 0.2794154981 9892587281,- 0.2794154981 9892587545],
     13
    [--,0.2151199880 878155243,0.2151199880 878155243],
      2
    [7,0.6569865987 187890904,0.6569865987 1878909041]]
                                                      Type: List List Any
```